# Intercept AND CHANGE the results of an ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I found some interesting (and working) answers for how to intercept an ajax call and see all of its content with javascript.([Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765031/scrape-eavesdrop-ajax-data-using-javascript) and [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073493/insert-content-script-when-page-was-changed-by-history-pushstate-and-ajax-call/31106499#31106499), ignoring the "timer approach" in answer 2).

I have a Chrome extension that works on a third's page. The page sends and receives its own ajax requests and mostly reshapes itself based on the received data. Currently, my extension can intercept and **see** the data received, but but it does not interfere in any of the ajax data.

Now I wish to go one step further and **change** the results **before** the page reshapes its HTML content!

#### Example:

User clicks a button, the page itself sends a request and receives a response with an array containing 100 elements to be displayed in a table. The page automatically creates the html table with 100 elements. Everything without my interference.

When the data is received, I can see the 100 elements received.

Now let's say I want the page to show only "50" of those elements instead of 100. How could I change the response received by the page?

Details:

- The page sends the request, not my extension (I could change the arguments sent, but that is not the best choice, I don't want to send bad requests to the server, which I cannot see or change anyhow).
- The page itself changes its DOM after receiving the response.
- I **do not want** to change the DOM! I need to change the data received **before** the page starts changing its DOM. (The amount of data received is so huge that the page gets slower than the movement of the continents, I need to prevent the elements from being created)
- The page is highly dynamic, using one of those "bootstrap-like" frameworks and most of its DOM elements are cleared and recreated each time a response is received.

Comment: [Intercept XMLHttpRequest and modify responseText](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959359) or [How can I modify the XMLHttpRequest responsetext received by another function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26447335) ?

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, I hadn't noticed the links. Yes! It seems the second link will work. I'll try it when I have the chance! Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I modify the XMLHttpRequest responsetext received by another function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447335/how-can-i-modify-the-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-received-by-another-function)

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm , the second link actually answers my question. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll check it as answered. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The important part of this method is the `Object.defineProperty` API.

You can't use object assignment to override, `this.responseText = {...};`

```js
<button>send</button>

<script>
  const nativeOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  const nativeSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

  const proxiedOpen = function () {
    // Mount the URL that needs to be intercepted to the `XMLHttpRequest` object.
    if (arguments[1].includes('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')) this._url = arguments[1];
    nativeOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  const proxiedSend = async function () {
    if (this._url) {
      // Make other requests, it can also be a fixed value.
      const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/5').then(res => res.json());
      // The data of `todos/1` is rewritten as `todos/5`
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'responseText', { value: JSON.stringify(data), writable: false });
    }
    nativeSend.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  // Override native methods
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = proxiedOpen;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = proxiedSend;

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText); // Will get the data of `todos/5` instead of `todos/1`.
      }
    };
    xhttp.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', true);
    xhttp.send();
  });
</script>
```